# How to focus and highlight a looped element while scrolling down using up and down keys?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/38zR3/376/) to highlight the rows of a looped element when scrolling up/down using keyboard keys up and down. But I can't make it to work on my html layout. Here is my code..

```
<div id="filterdiv" >
    <label id="resultnum" ></label> 
    <label id="scrolldummy"></label>
    <div id="navdiv">
        <div id="proddiv"><label id="prodlabel" style="height:30px;">Products </label></div>
        <div id="divcategory"><label id="categorylabel" style="height:30px;color:orange">All Categories</label></div>
        <div id="subcategorydiv"><label id="subcategorylabel" >All Sub Categories </label></div>
    </div>
    <div id="filtercontainerdiv" >
        <div id="dropdowndiv" > 
            <input type="text" id="txtloc" value="All Locations" readonly="true" title="Filter by Location"  />
            <div id="dropdowncontainer" >
                <input type="text" id="searchloc" class="searchloc"  onkeyup = "QueryLocatio()" placeholder="Search Location"  />
                <div id="dropdownlist" data-bind="foreach: PopulateAllLocation">
                     <div id="alllocationdiv" > <label id="listlocation" class="listlocation" data-bind="text: CityTown"></label></div>               
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
 // Highlight list of Location while pressing arrow down up key
        $('#dropdowncontainer').on('focus', '.listlocation', function () {
            $this = $(this);
            $this.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass();
            $this.closest('#dropdowncontainer').scrollTop($this.index() * $this.outerHeight());
        }).on('keydown', '.listlocation', function (e) {
            $this = $(this);
            if (e.keyCode == 40) {
                $this.next().focus();
                return false;
            } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
                $this.prev().focus();
                return false;
            }
        }).find('.listlocation').first().focus();
```

Please help..

Comment: Why this doesn't work? Do you have any error in console?

Comment: @CliffBurton No I don't see any errors in the console. It just doesn't work when I press the up down keys.

Comment: Do you think it's on my css because my css for active is just to highlight background color e.g. .active { background-color:lightgrey}. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you show your CSS?

Comment: I think this is because label is inside div. Try --- $this.next('.listlocation').focus();   and  $this.prev('.listlocation').focus();